# Plotting around a circunference

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there any possibilitie using matplotlib to get something like this:
[signlar with circular path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8QNf.png)
The plot is a signal acquired but wrapped or plotted through a circular path. Any idea?
original signal:
[Original signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T9sX.png)

Comment: You wanna convert your x axis to a range of 0 to 2*pi, i.e. 0 goes to 0 and 160 goes to 2pi, then use a matplotlib polar plot, where the r value is your signal magnitude. That will wrap your signal in the manner you need Is your x range your full range or should any of it overlap? Check this link for polar plotting in matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try a polar plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circum = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 1000)
rad = 2+np.random.random(1000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(circum, rad)
ax.set_rlim(0,5)
fig.show()
```

You would need to convert your x-y data into r-theta data though (this isn't too hard).